# How can I enable a major mode within a helm buffer?

Tags: org-mode, helm

I am trying to get org-mode syntax within a helm buffer. I want the candidates to render using org-mode syntax. How can I do this?

Comment: did you mean Org Mode's syntax highlight? I notice helm-org package's helm-org-in-buffer-headings command can produce the syntax highlight once you set helm-org-headings-fontify to t. Though I don't know how it works.

Comment: yes that is what I mean. helm-org-in-buffer-headings is a useful resource. From looking at it, the relievent function is https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-org/blob/b7a18dfc17e8b933956d61d68c435eee03a96c24/helm-org.el#L258-329

Comment: Helm-org finds the headings and displays them using `match-string`, so my guess is you don't set the major-mode explicitly. Instead you use text properties to fontify the candidates, for example using `buffer-substring` etc. See also `org-fontify-like-in-org-mode`.